# make test a feature is available or not return error

Tags: make

make -v return:

```
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

In a directory, one one file: makefile

```
ifneq ($(jobserver),T)
$(error This makefile only works with a Make program that supports $$(eval))
endif
```

invoke make by type make

```
makefile:2: *** This makefile only works with a Make program that supports $(eval).  Stop.
```

even I try

```
ifneq ($(eval),T)
$(error This makefile only works with a Make program that supports $$(eval))
endif
```

still return

```
makefile:2: *** This makefile only works with a Make program that supports $(eval).  Stop.
```

I follow the [tutorial](https://nostarch.com/gnumake) from online, these makefile test a feature/function in make is available or not. It should not yield error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re missing the *use* of `eval` which sets the variable before the test:

```make
$(eval eval_available := T)
ifneq ($(eval_available),T)
$(error This makefile only works with a Make program that supports $$(eval))
endif
```

If `eval` is available, the first line will set `eval_available` to `T`; if it isn’t, it won’t. The second line checks whether `eval_available` was set to `T`.